# Python - Parsing / extracting sections using Python

Tags: python, html, parsing

was hoping someone could give me some suggestions.

So, I have a large HTML document.  I need to extract data between 2 tags.   It's a dynamic document, so it can be different each time/   But there are a couple of constants.   The starting point of extraction will be the section that starts with "Notes to Unaudited Condensed".   You can see the section ID from the table of contents:

```
 <a href="#a1NatureofOperations_790426"><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;">Notes to Unaudited Condensed Consolidated Financial Statements</span></a></p></td>
```

Basically I want to extract all content up until the next section ID, which always starts with "Item 2.":

```
 <a href="#ITEM2MANAGEMENTSDISCUSSIONANDANALYSIS_77"><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;">Item 2.</span></a></p></td>
```

So, is there a way for me to get the tag ID from the anchor, and then I can search the document for that tag ID as the start / end of the parsing that is needed?

Or, perhaps there is some other Python HTML parser which can do much of the work for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there complete HTML example and the output you want to extract?

Comment: Hi Andrej, there could be N number of pages between the sections which I referred to above.  I want to extract all that content.  The only constants that are for sure, is that the section would begin with "Notes to Unaudited Condensed" and go until the next section, which begins with "Item 2.".    So, if I can somehow reference those tag ID's, I can use that as a start / end to extract the content possibly.

Comment: Traverse the _HTML_, and map the indices of every _anchor_ element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question. It seems like you want to extract a content of an HTML file between two tags. I recommend you to use the BeautifulSoup library, which is a popular HTML parser, you can use this code as an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    # Find the starting point with "Notes to Unaudited Condensed"
    start_tag = soup.find('a', {'href': '#a1NatureofOperations_790426'})

    if start_tag:
        # Get the ID of the starting tag
        start_id = start_tag['href'][1:]

        # Find the ending point with "Item 2."
        end_tag = soup.find('a', {'href': '#ITEM2MANAGEMENTSDISCUSSIONANDANALYSIS_77'})

        if end_tag:
            # Get the ID of the ending tag
            end_id = end_tag['href'][1:]

            # Extract content between the two tags
            extracted_content = soup.find('div', {'id': start_id}).find_next('div', {'id': end_id})

            if extracted_content:
                return extracted_content.get_text()

    # If the tags are not found, return None or handle accordingly
    return None

# Example usage
with open('your_html_file.html', 'r') as file:
    html_content = file.read()

result = extract_content(html_content)

if result:
    print(result)
else:
    print("Content extraction failed.")
```

This script assumes that your content is within `<div>` tags with the specified IDs. Adjust the tags and attributes accordingly based on your HTML structure.

Good luck! :D

Comment: Looks like the document is pretty sloppy, does not use <div> tags.  Instead, appears to use empty anchors with Id's:    <a id="a1NatureofOperations_790426"></a>

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible example how you can extract tags between two tags:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<div>
    Something other ...
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><span>Notes to Unaudited Condensed Consolidated Financial Statements</span></a>
</div>
<div>I want this...</div>
<div>I want this too...</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><span>Item 2.</span></a>
</div>
<div>I DON'T want this...</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

tag_start = soup.find(
    lambda tag: "Notes to Unaudited Condensed Consolidated Financial Statements"
    in tag.text,
    recursive=False,
)

tag_end = soup.find(
    lambda tag: "Item 2." in tag.text,
    recursive=False,
)

tags_in_between, state = [], False
for tag in soup.find_all(recursive=False):
    if tag is tag_start:
        state = True
    elif tag is tag_end:
        state = False
    elif state:
        tags_in_between.append(tag)

print(tags_in_between)
```

Prints:

```
[<div>I want this...</div>, <div>I want this too...</div>]
```